# Long Saving and Loading Time with GAS Web App

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been running into this problem with odd regularity.  Code working fine, and then it starts taking a couple minutes to save or load. It's about 2000 lines, so only on the larger-side of average. Well this problem found its way into my day today again, and I finally found the cause.

It turns out that all of my "slow code" had been copy and pasted, generally when I've used `Select All`.  I've been doing this as I deploy the apps to coworkers and the like, causing a far amount of frustration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this may sound obvious, but it seems the best practice for installing apps into other accounts is to share the script at viewer level and then make a copy.

I've also gone back to other slow code, tracked down a good version and made a copy and updated bit by bit.  Slow code now fast.